# How do I Unzip a file, replace a file with a new copy and re-zip the file in Apple script?

Tags: applescript

I have a string with the path to a .ipa file:

```
set ipa_path to POSIX path of ipa_file
```

Now I want to:

1. Un-zip the .ipa file (its really a zip file)
2. Replace a file in the zip called "embedded.mobileprovision" with a new version of the file.
3. Re-zip the file and replace the original ipa file.

So for I have:

```
do shell script "unzip " & ipa_path
```

Is this right so far?  I just started to learn AppleScript today ...

Answer (score -1):

You don't really need AppleScript for this. The command line `zip` utility has the `-r` option to replace existing files (of the same name and relative path) within a zip archive. Here's a quote from the [man page `man zip`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=zip&sektion=1&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%209.0-RELEASE%20and%20Ports):

```
if foo.zip exists and contains foo/file1 and foo/file2, and the
directory  foo  contains the files foo/file1 and foo/file3, then:
   zip -r foo.zip foo
will  replace foo/file1 in foo.zip and add foo/file3 to foo.zip.
```

Of course, you can still wrap the calls to `zip` in AppleScript `do shell script` commands.